# When to use static methods

Tags: java, static-methods

I am wondering when to use static methods? Say if I have a class with a few getters and setters, a method or two, and I want those methods only to be invokable on an instance object of the class. Does this mean I should use a static method?

Example:

```
Obj x = new Obj();
x.someMethod();
```

...or:

```
Obj.someMethod(); // Is this the static way?
```

I'm rather confused!

Answer (score 1650, accepted):

One rule-of-thumb: ask yourself "Does it make sense to call this method, even if no object has been constructed yet?"  If so, it should definitely be static.

So in a class `Car` you might have a method:

```
double convertMpgToKpl(double mpg)
```

...which would be static, because one might want to know what 35mpg converts to, even if nobody has ever built a `Car`.  But this method (which sets the efficiency of one particular `Car`):

```
void setMileage(double mpg)
```

...can't be static since it's inconceivable to call the method before any `Car` has been constructed.

(By the way, the converse isn't always true: you might sometimes have a method which involves two `Car` objects, and still want it to be static.  E.g.:

```
Car theMoreEfficientOf(Car c1, Car c2)
```

Although this could be converted to a non-static version, some would argue that since there isn't a "privileged" choice of which `Car` is more important, you shouldn't force a caller to choose one `Car` as the object you'll invoke the method on.  This situation accounts for a fairly small fraction of all static methods, though.

Comment: A few good examples here.  I would add, however, that "static" is often valuable when you know something is not going to change across instances.  If this is the case, I would really consider the "Single Responsability Principle", which implies a class should have one responsability and thus only one reason to change.  I feel one should consider moving the "ConvertMpgToKpl(double mpg)" function, and similar methods, to their own class. The purpose of a car object is to allow instantiation of cars, not provide a comparison between them.  Those should be external to the class.

Comment: I think I would rather the method `Car#isMoreEfficientThan(Car)`. It has the advantage that which car you return in a tie isn't arbitrary. It's obvious by the title of the method what is returned in a tie.

Comment: I would also be careful about creating a static method that is using some external resource (filesystem, database, etc) this type of static can make it horrendous to test the consuming methods.

I personally try to keep statics in the realm of "utility."

Comment: In fact, it should be implemented as a [Comparator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm).

Comment: just to simply add ,when you don't have any data/code dependency go for static else if data comes into picture its simply private(preferably)/public

Comment: @Cruncher shouldn't `isMoreEfficientThan(...)` return a `boolean`? (`true` if more efficient, `false` if as or less efficient)

Comment: @B1KMusic Of course. What I mean by "which car is returned in a tie" is "true maps to the called on car, and false maps to the passed car". It's without ambiguity.

Comment: Am I save to assume that any basic linear script running as a JAR on a linux machine should be static? For example a java program which processes a bunch of files by filtering (Blacklist/whitelist), packaging and deposits them in a archive directory. Basically all your classes are Utility classes which the main calls directly. Is this correct?

Comment: @KennySteegmans  No, I think it's unrelated.  For example, I could envision a 'class FileList', perhaps even with sub-classes 'ImageFileList' and 'AppFileList' etc., and so you might use an OO system.  Admittedly, that's *probably* overkill in the situation you describe, and a bunch of well-designed static methods would probably suffice.  (And of course, you would launch your program running by calling a static method (`main`).)

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. I now know java static method is shared by all instances of a certain class, dose it mean each instance has its own non-static method like non-static variable? Thanks.

Comment: is there a general statement regarding state/sideeffects of static methods?

Comment: -1 The example methods `double convertMpgToKpl(double mpg)` and `Car theMoreEfficientOf( Car c1, Car c2 )` are clearly not the methods of Car class. And today, in 2017, in the age of DI and loose coupling, these methods should not be static at all even in another class.

Comment: Contrary to some of the comments, I actually appreciate the second example. Even though it may not be the best method in practical use, it helped me understand the answer to the question better.

Comment: @TomBrito No performance considerations as there's no performance difference after the code gets JIT compiled. Virtual method calls are expensive, but they obviously don't apply when the method can be static. Method is classes without ancestors get special treatment and so do non-overridden methods (whether `final` or not).

Answer (score 607):

Define static methods in the following scenarios only:

1. If you are writing utility classes and they are not supposed to be changed.
2. If the method is not using any instance variable.
3. If any operation is not dependent on instance creation.
4. If there is some code that can easily be shared by all the instance methods, extract that code into a static method.
5. If you are sure that the definition of the method will never be changed or overridden. As static methods can not be overridden.

Comment: good points, but they are requirements if you *want* to make a method static, not reasons to make one.

Comment: @Mohd about requirement 5:
When can you be 100% sure a method will never be changed or overridden? Aren't there always unknown factors you can't take in account at the moment you write your static method?

Comment: "Utility-Classes" are very difficult to reason about, the bad thing is that sooner or later everything starts 'looking like' an utility (yeah I'm referring to that "util" package that is bloated, untouchable and poorly tested), and your test cases will need more work (to mock static utils is HARD). Prefer objects first.

Comment: @Mohd this answer is exactly what I am looking for. I faced a lot of problems using static methods in multithreading. Can you please elaborate points 2, 3 more (with example 100 thumbs up for you)

Comment: I think a "static class" should be invented if you are going to use static variables and methods.

Comment: Shouldnt 4 be an instance method? No need to make it static no?

Answer (score 220):

There are some valid reasons to use static methods:

- **Performance**: if you want some code to be run, and don't want to instantiate an extra object to do so, shove it into a static method. The JVM also can optimize static methods a lot (I think I've once read James Gosling declaring that you don't need custom instructions in the JVM, since static methods will be just as fast, but couldn't find the source - thus it could be completely false). Yes, it is micro-optimization, and probably unneeded. And we programmers never do unneeded things just because they are cool, right?
- **Practicality**: instead of calling `new Util().method(arg)`, call `Util.method(arg)`, or `method(arg)` with static imports. Easier, shorter.
- **Adding methods**: you really wanted the class String to have a `removeSpecialChars()` instance method, but it's not there (and it shouldn't, since your project's special characters may be different from the other project's), and you can't add it (since Java is somewhat sane), so you create an utility class, and call `removeSpecialChars(s)` instead of `s.removeSpecialChars()`. Sweet.
- **Purity**: taking some precautions, your static method will be a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), that is, the only thing it depends on is its parameters. Data in, data out. This is easier to read and debug, since you don't have inheritance quirks to worry about. You can do it with instance methods too, but the compiler will help you a little more with static methods (by not allowing references to instance attributes, overriding methods, etc.).

You'll also have to create a static method if you want to make a singleton, but... don't. I mean, think twice.

Now, more importantly, *why you wouldn't want* to create a static method? Basically, **polymorphism goes out of the window**. You'll not be able to override the method, <strike>nor declare it in an interface</strike> *(pre-Java 8)*. It takes a lot of flexibility out from your design. Also, if you need **state**, you'll end up with lots of **concurrency bugs** and/or bottlenecks if you are not careful.

Comment: A lot of good reasons listed here on when static can be useful. One more I can think of is that writing unit tests for such methods is just plain simple

Comment: @tetsuo Thanks! Your explanation is very clear and the reasons provided are very logical and make a lot of sense.

Comment: *And we programmers never do unneeded things just because they are cool, right?* +1

Comment: That said a static method becomes a full named function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: I agree with Performance and Practicality, but not Purity.   The static method can modify static members of the class (which may be private).  This can be useful.  For example, you could have a method like "static synchronized int allocateID() {return idNext++;}".  In fact, a static method can be just as pure or impure as a non-static method in terms of side effects.

Comment: @AdamGawne-Cain Fair enough, Java is not a functional language, and has no real support for pure functions.

I guess my thought process when I wrote this was, since with static methods you give up many features - such as polymorphism, dynamic binding, inheritance and instance scopes - it would be easier to keep methods pure, since you only have to worry about not using any class state, and only calling other pure methods.

But yes, you're right, it still shares many concerns about side effects with instance methods.

Answer (score 46):

After reading Misko's articles I believe that [static methods](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html) are bad from a testing point of view. You should have [factories](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone) instead(maybe using a dependency injection tool like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)).

### how do I ensure that I only have one of something

> only have one of something
>   The problem of “how do I ensure that I
>   only have one of something” is nicely
>   sidestepped. You instantiate only a
>   single ApplicationFactory in your
>   main, and as a result, you only
>   instantiate a single instance of all
>   of your singletons.

### The basic issue with static methods is they are procedural code

> The basic issue with static methods is
>   they are procedural code. I have no
>   idea how to unit-test procedural code.
>   Unit-testing assumes that I can
>   instantiate a piece of my application
>   in isolation. During the instantiation
>   I wire the dependencies with
>   mocks/friendlies which replace the
>   real dependencies. With procedural
>   programing there is nothing to "wire"
>   since there are no objects, the code
>   and data are separate.

Comment: I don't understand the part about not being able to unit-test procedural code. Don't you just set up test cases that map correct input to correct output using the static method together with the class as your "unit"?

Comment: You could do that to test those functions. But when using these static methods in other classes you want to test, I believe you can't fake them(mocks/friendlies) or anything, because you can not instantiate a class.

Comment: But can't static methods only access static members?, If my understanding of this is correct then how could instantiation of the class make a difference?

Comment: Have you read the complete article => http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/? You should try to understand the 3rd paragraph about seams/isolation. Especially the last line of the 3rd paragraph => " Yes, static methods are easy to call, but if the static method calls another static method there is no way to overrider the called method dependency."

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that paragraph, after reading all three articles I think I'm beginning to understand.

Comment: I hope so. You could also watch a video from misko explaining testing a bit => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w. There are even more video's available at youtube.

Comment: @Alfred: Please have a look at [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which has the ability to mock static methods. Using PowerMock there are few scenarios, if any, where you find method dependencies which cannot be mocked.

Comment: "Are You stupid or from Google?"

Please go away with that guy. Programming is not just all about unit testing.

And if You are a bad programmer - then unit testing is the only way You can write working software.

Comment: You can unit test statics using PowerMock, however you'll soon find you run out of Permgen space (done that, got the T-shirt), and its still nasty. Unless you KNOW (based on at least a decade of your own experience in true OO languages, not migrating from C) then DON'T DO IT. Seriously, the worst code I've ever seen came from an embedded developer's use of statics and in most cases we were stuck with it, forever, and adding more code just locked us into the unmodifiable monolith even more tightly. Loose coupling: no, testable: barely, modifiable: NEVER.  Avoid!

Comment: I can understand the difficulty of testing static methods that depend on static state.  But when you're testing *stateless* static methods like `Math.abs()` or `Arrays.sort()`, even methods you can *pass all dependencies into*, I don't see how that would ever impede unit testing.  I would say a simple rule of thumb is: if you'd ever have any reason to mock out the procedural logic, then don't put it in a static method.  I've never had a reason to mock out `Arrays.sort()` or `Math.abs()`.

Comment: @Andy If you are pulling in all the dependencies, then you are not "Unit testing" the Static method anymore. You are indirectly testing the dependencies of the static method. It's a not unit test anymore.

Comment: @user6123723 I was talking about passing mocks of the dependencies into the method being tested

Comment: @Andy Fair enough!

Comment: It's 2022, and +1 to Andy's comment.

Answer (score 38):

A `static` method is one type of method which doesn't need any object to be initialized for it to be called. Have you noticed `static` is used in the `main` function in Java? Program execution begins from there without an object being created.

Consider the following example:

```
 class Languages 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         display();
     }

     static void display() 
     {
         System.out.println("Java is my favorite programming language.");
     }
  }
```

Comment: best answer actually

Answer (score 22):

Static methods in java belong to the class (not an instance of it). They use no instance variables and will usually take input from the parameters, perform actions on it, then return some result. Instances methods are associated with objects and, as the name implies, can use instance variables.

Answer (score 13):

No, static methods aren't associated with an instance; they belong to the class.  Static methods are your second example; instance methods are the first.

Comment: You should use static methods if don't need object's state manipulations.

Answer (score 13):

If you apply static keyword with any method, it is known as static method.

1. A static method belongs to the class rather than object of a class.
2. A static method invoked without the need for creating an instance of a class.
3. static method can access static data member and can change the value of it.
4. A static method can be accessed just using the name of a class dot static name  . . . example : Student9.change();
5. If you want to use non-static fields of a class, you must use a non-static method.

//Program of changing the common property of all objects(static field).

```
class Student9{  
 int rollno;  
 String name;  
 static String college = "ITS";  

 static void change(){  
 college = "BBDIT";  
 }  

 Student9(int r, String n){  
 rollno = r;  
 name = n;  
 }  

 void display (){System.out.println(rollno+" "+name+" "+college);}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
Student9.change();  

Student9 s1 = new Student9 (111,"Indian");  
Student9 s2 = new Student9 (222,"American");  
Student9 s3 = new Student9 (333,"China");  

s1.display();  
s2.display();  
s3.display();  
}  }
```

O/P:   111 Indian BBDIT
       222 American BBDIT
       333 China BBDIT

Answer (score 11):

Static methods should be called on the Class, Instance methods should be called on the Instances of the Class.  But what does that mean in reality?  Here is a useful example:

A car class might have an instance method called Accelerate().  You can only Accelerate a car, if the car actually exists (has been constructed) and therefore this would be an instance method.

A car class might also have a count method called GetCarCount().  This would return the total number of cars created (or constructed).  If no cars have been constructed, this method would return 0, but it should still be able to be called, and therefore it would have to be a static method.

Answer (score 10):

Static methods are not associated with an instance, so they can not access any non-static fields in the class.

You would use a static method if the method does not use any fields (or only static fields) of a class.

If any non-static fields of a class are used you must use a non-static method.

Comment: Clear, short and simple answer.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, we use static properties and methods in a class, when we want to use some part of our program should exists there until our program is running. And we know that, to manipulate static properties, we need static methods as they are not a part of instance variable. And without static methods, to manipulate static properties is time consuming.

Comment: Keeping state in static variables is a bad thing to do for many reasons - like multi-threading safety, debugging, data-encapsulation..etc etc
Static methods are OK if they are pure functions (work with params only, without changing them).
Good example would be an utility class, for say math calculations.

Answer (score 5):

Use a static method when you want to be able to access the method without an instance of the class.

Comment: This does not give any rationale for the design of a program.

Comment: yes give a proper example to back your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Static:
`Obj.someMethod`

Use `static` when you want to provide class level access to a method, i.e. where the method should be callable without an instance of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Static methods don't need to be invoked on the object and that is when you use it. Example: your Main()  is a static and you don't create an object to call it.

Comment: Yay! Look where I came while googling Java noobie questions!  It's a small world :-)

Comment: @Deepak small world indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

Static methods and variables are controlled version of 'Global' functions and variables in Java. In which methods can be accessed as `classname.methodName()` or `classInstanceName.methodName()`, i.e. static methods and variables can be accessed using class name as well as instances of the class.

Class can't be declared as static(because it makes no sense. if a class is declared public, it can be accessed from anywhere), inner classes can be declared static.

Answer (score 4):

Static methods can be used if

- One does not want to perform an action on an instance (utility methods)

  > As mentioned in few of above answers in this post, converting miles to kilometers, or calculating temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice-versa. With these examples using static method, it does not need to instantiate whole new object in heap memory. Consider below

  ```
  1. new ABCClass(double farenheit).convertFarenheitToCelcium() 
  2. ABCClass.convertFarenheitToCelcium(double farenheit)
  ```

  > the former creates a new class footprint for every method invoke, ***Performance, Practical***. Examples are Math and Apache-Commons library StringUtils class below:

  ```
  Math.random()
  Math.sqrt(double)
  Math.min(int, int)
  StringUtils.isEmpty(String)
  StringUtils.isBlank(String)
  ```
- One wants to use as a simple function. Inputs are explictly passed, and getting the result data as return value. Inheritence, object instanciation does not come into picture. ***Concise, Readable***.

**NOTE**: 
Few folks argue against testability of static methods, but static methods can be tested too! With jMockit, one can mock static methods. ***Testability***. Example below:

```
new MockUp<ClassName>() {
    @Mock
    public int doSomething(Input input1, Input input2){
        return returnValue;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Static methods are the methods in Java that can be called without creating an object of class.  It is belong to the class.

We use static method when we no need to be invoked method using instance.

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice description, when to use static methods:

There is no hard and fast, well written rules, to decide when to make a method static or not, But there are few observations based upon experience, which not only help to make a method static but also teaches when to use static method in Java. You should consider making a method static in Java :

1. If a method doesn't modify state of object, or not using any instance variables.
2. You want to call method without creating instance of that class.
3. A method is good candidate of being static, if it only work on arguments provided to it e.g. public int factorial(int number){}, this method only operate on number provided as argument.
4. Utility methods are also good candidate of being static e.g. StringUtils.isEmpty(String text), this a utility method to check if a String is empty or not.
5. If function of method will remain static across class hierarchy e.g. equals() method is not a good candidate of making static because every Class can redefine equality.

Source is [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/07/when-to-make-method-static-in-java.html#axzz6kkmIGI21)

Answer (score 4):

You should use static methods whenever,

1. The code in the method is not dependent on instance creation and is
   not using any instance variable.
2. A particular piece of code is to be shared by all the instance methods.
3. The definition of the method should not be changed or overridden.
4. you are writing utility classes that should not be changed.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/When-to-use-static-methods-in-Java

Answer (score 3):

A static method has two main purposes:

1. For utility or helper methods that don't require any object state.
   Since there is no need to access instance variables, having static
   methods eliminates the need for the caller to instantiate the object
   just to call the method.
2. For the state that is shared by all
   instances of the class, like a counter. All instance must share the
   same state. Methods that merely use that state should be static as
   well.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you can enable a warning which helps you detect potential static methods. (Above the highlighted line is another one I forgot to highlight)

[image: eclipse setting]

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering when to use static methods?

1. A common use for `static` methods is to access `static` fields.
2. But you can have `static` methods, without referencing `static` variables. Helper methods without referring `static` variable can be found in some java classes like [java.lang.Math](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java/?v=source)

   ```
   public static int min(int a, int b) {
       return (a <= b) ? a : b;
   }
   ```
3. The other use case, I can think of these methods combined with `synchronized` method is implementation of class level locking in multi threaded environment.

> Say if I have a class with a few getters and setters, a method or two, and I want those methods only to be invokable on an instance object of the class. Does this mean I should use a static method?

If you need to access method on an instance object of the class, your method should should be non static.

Oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) provides more details.

Not all combinations of instance and class variables and methods are allowed:

1. Instance methods can access instance variables and instance methods directly.
2. Instance methods can access class variables and class methods directly.
3. Class methods can access class variables and class methods directly.
4. Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference. Also, class methods cannot use the this keyword as there is no instance for this to refer to.

Comment: Can't we access static fields through regular methods? Then this `A common use for static methods is to access static fields.` is not an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do not want to create an object to call a method in your code just declare that method as static. Since the static method does not need an instance to be called with but the catch here is not all static methods are called by JVM automatically. This privilege is enjoyed only by the main() "public static void main[String... args]" method in java because at Runtime this is the method Signature public "static" void main[] sought by JVM as an entry point to start execution of the code.

Example:

```
public class Demo
{
   public static void main(String... args) 
   {
      Demo d = new Demo();

      System.out.println("This static method is executed by JVM");

     //Now to call the static method Displ() you can use the below methods:
           Displ(); //By method name itself    
      Demo.Displ(); //By using class name//Recommended
         d.Displ(); //By using instance //Not recommended
   }

   public static void Displ()
   {
      System.out.println("This static method needs to be called explicitly");
   }
}
```

Output:-
This static method is executed by JVM
This static method needs to be called explicitly
This static method needs to be called explicitly
This static method needs to be called explicitly

Answer (score 0):

In Java, static methods are methods that belong to a class rather than an instance of the class. They are called on the class itself, rather than on an object created from that class. Static methods have several common use cases:

Utility Methods: Static methods are often used for creating utility functions that don't depend on the state of any particular instance but provide general functionality. These methods are typically placed in utility classes or helper classes.

```
public class MathUtils {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static double squareRoot(double value) {
        return Math.sqrt(value);
    }
}

// Usage
int sum = MathUtils.add(5, 3);
double sqrt = MathUtils.squareRoot(16.0);
```

Factory Methods: Static methods can be used to create and return instances of a class. For example, the getInstance() method in the Singleton pattern.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() {
        // Private constructor to prevent direct instantiation
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

// Usage
Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
```

I'll create a Car class with a static method to calculate the average miles per gallon (MPG) for a group of cars.

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private double fuelEfficiency; // Miles per gallon (MPG)

    public Car(String make, String model, double fuelEfficiency) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public double getFuelEfficiency() {
        return fuelEfficiency;
    }

    public double calculateMilesPerGallon(double gallons) {
        return gallons * fuelEfficiency;
    }

    // Static method to calculate the average MPG for a group of cars
    public static double calculateAverageMPG(Car[] cars) {
        if (cars.length == 0) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        double totalMPG = 0;
        for (Car car : cars) {
            totalMPG += car.getFuelEfficiency();
        }

        return totalMPG / cars.length;
    }
}
```

In this Car class, we have a static method called calculateAverageMPG that takes an array of Car objects as a parameter and calculates the average MPG of all the cars in the array. This static method does not depend on any particular instance of the Car class and can be called using the class name, like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car("Toyota", "Camry", 30.0);
        Car car2 = new Car("Honda", "Civic", 35.0);
        Car car3 = new Car("Ford", "Focus", 28.0);

        Car[] cars = {car1, car2, car3};

        double averageMPG = Car.calculateAverageMPG(cars);
        System.out.println("Average MPG for the group of cars: " + averageMPG);
    }
}
```

In this example, we create three Car objects and calculate the average MPG for the group of cars using the static calculateAverageMPG method.

Answer (score -1):

The only reasonable place to use static methods are probably `Math` functions, and of course `main()` must be `static`, and maybe small factory-methods. But logic should not be kept in static methods.

Comment: No they are very different from global variables. The problem with a global variable is that it's very hard to track where they are being modified from. A static method can't be modified so doesn't have that problem. They are fine

Comment: @DavidW I never said anything about global variables. I suggest you read the answers more carefully next time.

Comment: Sorry you're quite right you didn't say anything about global variables. I still disagree though - there's nothing wrong with a global function either.

Comment: For example `Math.sin`. There's no state associated with it. It takes a number in and returns a number out. So it may as well be static or global. There's no need to instantiate a pointless empty class for it.

Comment: @DavidW `Math` functions is a rare exception to this, and I agree, `Math.sin()` and `cos()` can be static. But that's it.

Comment: But for regular logic in your application (persistence, view, domain, business) static methods shouldn't be used.

Comment: You can effectively consider a constructor a static method (it doesn't depend on having an instance of a class), and factory functions are also static methods. Are you proposing to ban those?

Comment: @DavidW Please don't try to take my argument out of propotions to have me say we should ban constructors. I'm not trying to come up with some absolute ban. What I'm saying, is that in normal situations regular methods and constructors are perfectly valid choice for virtually all projects, and `static` methods should never be used, with the limited exception of maybe `Math`. If you're creating services, repositories, views, utitlities or other classes and declare them `static`, you're making it harder for yourself.